# SML using datatypes to add and subtract

Tags: types, sml

I was wondering how to create a datatypes and that can aid in evaluating a string
that contains ("1 + 2")

I was thinking of making a datatype

```
datatype opp = oper of string;
datatype numm = numb of int;
datatype calc = opp | numm;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say

```
datatype expr = Number of int | Add of expr * expr;
```

along with

```
 fun calc(Number(x)) = x
   | calc(Add(x, y)) = calc(x) + calc(y);
```

would do the trick. However, once you start adding more operators you need to think about associativity and operator precedence.

Comment: So how would you call (1 + 3)? would you just put into calc(exp(1 +3)) sorry I am new to ML.

Comment: @user3312266 You do `calc(Add(Number(1), Number(3)))`

Comment: My understanding is that one generally handles associativity and precedence in the parser rather than in the evaluator. You parse `2+3*8` into `Add(Number(2),Multiply(Number(3),Number(8)))` and not `Multiply(Add(Number(2),Number(3)),Number(8))`. The evaluator remains fairly simple.